# Вытащить запись из таблицы по уникальному ключу

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM `G_news` WHERE (SELECT column_name
FROM   information_schema.key_column_usage WHERE  table_schema = schema() AND    constraint_name = 'PRIMARY'  AND    table_name = 'G_news') = 33;
```

Вот, что пришло на ум, но что то выдает пустоту. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно достать запись по primary key

Answer (score 1):

Здесь нужно использовать динамический SQL, т.е. собрать строку запроса, а потом ее выполнить.

Comment: а можно подробнее пожалуйста, первый раз слышу про динамику

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/execute.html

Answer (score 0):

Месье знает толк в извращениях =)

Всё гораздо проще!

Код на [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b4509/1)

P.S.: что бы не думать как увеличивать id, есть параметр `auto_increment` который всё сделает за вас.

Comment: не плохо, только нужен запрос, который именно по праймари кей (имя колонки мы не знаем) достает данные из базы